# How to resolve basic borrow issues?

Tags: rust

I'm pretty new to rust and I'm stuck on whats probably a very simple question about borrowing. I've simplified my code to as below:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub val: i32
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        MyStruct {
            val
        }
    }
}

pub struct MyStructVec {
    pub vec: Vec::<MyStruct>
}

impl MyStructVec {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
    MyStructVec {
           vec: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, mut my_struct: MyStruct) {
        self.vec.push(my_struct);
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        for s in self.vec.iter_mut() {
            s.val = s.val + 1;
            self.edit(s);
        }
    }

    fn edit(&self, my_struct: &mut MyStruct) {
        my_struct.val = my_struct.val * 2;
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut my_struct1 = MyStruct::new(69);
    let mut my_struct2 = MyStruct::new(420);
    let mut my_struct_vec = MyStructVec::new();
    my_struct_vec.insert(my_struct1);
    my_struct_vec.insert(my_struct2);

    my_struct_vec.run();
}
```

When I run this i get the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:33:13
   |
31 |         for s in self.vec.iter_mut() {
   |                  -------------------
   |                  |
   |                  mutable borrow occurs here
   |                  mutable borrow later used here
32 |             s.val = s.val + 1;
33 |             self.edit(s);
   |             ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

But if I edit my code like this:

```
    fn run(&mut self) {
        for s in self.vec.iter_mut() {
            s.val = s.val + 1;
            //self.edit(s);
            s.val = s.val * 2;
        }
    }
```

Then it runs perfectly fine. This examples a simplified case but in my actual code I might just want to separate out my code into a separate function for easier readability like with the edit function. So what is the proper way to do this in Rust? Thanks very much!

Comment: Why have `MyStructVec::edit` receive an immutable reference to `self` when it doesn't use it?

Comment: *"I might just want to separate out my code into a separate function for easier readability"* - the function signature is your contract with the compiler. The `edit()` function says it needs a reference to self, but you're also needing to mutate part of `self` at the same time, which is not allowed. If you need something from `self` when editing a `MyStruct`, then you should have a function with only those parts so they can't conflict. Code separation should follow contract separation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is that for some reason you are making your `MyStructVec` modify `MyStruct` when it could be simple a method on `MyStruct`. You are messing around with more references that you need, and you are not really taking the ones you need. It seems fair that `edit` should be encapsulated in the object that is gonna modify:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
...
    
    fn edit(&mut self) {
        self.val = self.val * 2;
    }
}
...

impl MyStructVec {
...
    fn run(&mut self) {
        for s in self.vec.iter_mut() {
            s.val = s.val + 1;
            s.edit();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b5470915cb55e5d437ee26b520a1d9f)